# Uppercase is not respected in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with PHP and MySQL:

An user with account:

```
username: StAr
password: 4LasK4
```

Can login with:

```
username: star
password: 4lask4
```

Uppercases are not respected.

What may be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I would suspect you're using a case insensitive table collation.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Comment: I check immediately in phpmyadmin

Comment: Should the user "Star" really be a different user than "star"? For the password, if it is correctly hashed, you would not be able to search case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collation determines whether two strings are equal. You should change the collation for the username and password columns to case sensitive or binary. For example:

```
alter table TableName modify username varchar(xx) collate utf8_bin,
    modify password varchar(xx) collate utf8_bin;
```

Comment: Now I have latin1_swedish_ci so have I change it into utf8_bin?

Comment: Also ascii_bin it is ok? Thanks very much

Comment: Use latin1_bin: note that your usernames are restricted to western european and american languages.

Comment: With latin1_swedish_ci your usernames would be sorted according to Swedish rules, for example á is would be sorted with a but ä would go after z.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the column definition and make sure your collation is not case insensitive (ci). You can try with this:

```
alter table your_table modify username varchar(xx) collate utf8_bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Many MySQL installations have a default collation setting of utf8_general_ci. This makes these  two operations yield precisely the same result.

```
 SELECT * from users WHERE name = 'StAr'
 SELECT * from users WHERE name = 'star'
```

You can try ALTERing the collation for your name column in your database. Or you can use a query like this:

```
     SELECT * from users WHERE name = 'StAr' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

This utf8_bin collation compares for precise equality. If you put the COLLATE in your query, however, you may disable the use of an index for the query and cause MySQL performance trouble.